# Google Filament rendering engine segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, valgrind, unordered-map

I am attempting to compile the sample app "Suzanne" from the Filament library, by statically linking to the appropriate libraries. Both the sample app and libraries have been compiled from the latest source code. I am compiling with clang++.

However, when I compile and run the app, I get a `segmentation fault`. `valgrind` gives the following output:

```
==31202== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==31202==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==31202==    at 0x46A485: size (__hash_table:809)
==31202==    by 0x46A485: bucket_count (__hash_table:1197)
==31202==    by 0x46A485: std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, void*>*> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::find<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (__hash_table:2334)
==31202==    by 0x461CA7: find (unordered_map:1205)
==31202==    by 0x461CA7: image::KtxBundle::getMetadata(char const*, unsigned long*) const (KtxBundle.cpp:274)
==31202==    by 0x463D26: image::KtxBundle::getSphericalHarmonics(filament::math::details::TVec3<float>*) (KtxBundle.cpp:290)
==31202==    by 0x420E69: IBL::loadFromKtx(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /home/joel/Documents/KiwiTest/filament-suzanne/out/suzanne)
==31202==    by 0x42162D: IBL::loadFromDirectory(utils::Path const&) (in /home/joel/Documents/KiwiTest/filament-suzanne/out/suzanne)
==31202==    by 0x41A41C: FilamentApp::loadIBL(Config const&) (in /home/joel/Documents/KiwiTest/filament-suzanne/out/suzanne)
==31202==    by 0x415D19: FilamentApp::run(Config const&, std::__1::function<void (filament::Engine*, filament::View*, filament::Scene*)>, std::__1::function<void (filament::Engine*, filament::View*, filament::Scene*)>, std::__1::function<void (filament::Engine*, filament::View*)>, std::__1::function<void (filament::Engine*, filament::View*, filament::Scene*, filament::Renderer*)>, std::__1::function<void (filament::Engine*, filament::View*, filament::Scene*, filament::Renderer*)>, unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /home/joel/Documents/KiwiTest/filament-suzanne/out/suzanne)
==31202==    by 0x40A1D4: main (in /home/joel/Documents/KiwiTest/filament-suzanne/out/suzanne)
==31202==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==31202==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==31202==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==31202==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==31202==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this and what I could do to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to find the line where the segfault is thrown? Unless this is a new issue which appeared after statically linking, its likely your code at fault

Comment: Yes, I'll certainly try that. The thing is, I'm just using *their* sample app, which compiles file when building the entire source code all together with cmake. I don't know why statically linking should have changed anything?..

Comment: Interesting... That is weird... What _might_ have happened is it included the wrong headers so has wrong sized definitions. Do you have multiple versions of this app on your computer?

Comment: That's a good shout, because initially I was using an older, precompiled version of the libraries. I'll see if that checks out...

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error resolved (courtesy of TheGoldKnight23): The header files in use were outdated.